# How many paths of length $7$ are there in a complete graph $K_{12}$ between vertices $A$ and $B$?

Tags: graph-theory

I have following to solve: I have a $K_{12}$ complete graph and should find all possible paths (exactly with length equal to $7$) between graph vertices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: How many paths of length 1 are there between $a$ and $b$? How many of length 2? Length 3? ...

Comment: Did you intend $K_{12}$ rather than $K_12$?  (I hope so, since I changed it to the former.)

Comment: Your edit is all right.

Answer (score 5):

If $A, B$ are fixed vertices, then this is equivalent to finding a permutation of 6 vertices out of 10.

If the starting and ending vertices are not fixed, then this is equivalent to finding a permutation of 8 vertices out of 12.

Comment: Can you explain why? Why is it not permutation of 7 out of 11 - this would give me more sense since you always have to count the last vertice for path but not the starting vertice?

Comment: @Kozuch Updated, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry I sent my comment by mistake. Just edited it, please re-read. I do not understand what you mean by "fixed vertices" - I guess the assignment says you can choose any 2 since the graph is "symmetric"?

Comment: If your starting and ending vertices are fixed as vertex A and vertex B (out of vertices A, B, C, D, E, ... ), then it's the 1st paragraph. Otherwise, if you're looking for all paths of length 7 (without caring about the starting and ending vertices), then it's the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Ok I get the "fixed vertices" thing now :). The assignment has not any details about fixed vertices at all (I posted all I have), but the letters A and B probably were meant to show them as fixed. So would you please explain background of your thinking for solution in 1st paragraph? Why 6 and why 10?

Comment: @Kozuch The path must be of the form $A - V_1 - V_2 - V_3 - V_4 - V_5 - V_6 - B$. What are the possibilities for $V_i$?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach considers the adjacency matrix of the graph: Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, fix an enumeration, and define its adjacency matrix $A=A_G$ to be the $n\times n$ matrix with entries $1$ or $0$, whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ iff there is an edge in $G$ between the $i$th and the $j$th vertices. An easy induction verifies that the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^m$ is precisely the number of paths of length exactly $m$ between the $i$th and the $j$th vertices.

In the case that concerns us, $G=K_{12}$, so $A=J-I$ where $J$ is the $12\times 12$ matrix, all of whose entries are $1$, and $I$ is the identity. Since $J$ and $I$ commute, $(J-I)^7$ can be found via the binomial theorem, using that $J^m$ is the matrix all of whose entries equal $12^{m-1}$, as another easy induction verifies. Note the final answer is different depending on whether the two vertices coincide or not. Specifically, the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^7$ is 
 $$ 12^6-7\times 12^5+\binom72 12^4-\binom73 12^3+\binom 74 12^2-\binom 75 12+7\times 1-c,$$
where $c=1$ if $i=j$ and $c=0$ otherwise. Note that this is just 
 $$ \frac{(12-1)^7+1}{12}-c=\frac {11^7+1}{12}-c=1623931-c, $$
that is, if the two vertices $i$ and $j$ are the same, then there are exactly $1\,623\,930$ paths between them, and otherwise there are $1\,623\,931$ paths. Note that some of these paths may pass through some vertices more than once.